# add choice picture in create account liferay

Tags: liferay

I want add the page after to complete the registration in liferay portal, user can insert your image, and then Login portlet page is displayed.
To do this, what should I do?
In addition, for the first time only login the choice should be

Comment: Could you please explain exact scenario you want so we can help you?

Comment: >  In addition, for the first time only login the choice should be

I really don't understand what you are trying to explain here. Can you plz clarify this with more details?

Answer (score 1):

> I want add the page after to complete the registration in liferay portal, user can insert your image, and then Login portlet page is displayed. To do this, what should I do?

For this, Create a Hook for login portlet.

ref : webapps/ROOT/html/portlet/login/create_account.jsp

Answer (score 0):

- custom post login action

  - create hook plugin
  - in src/main/resources , create portal.properties and put:

    > login.events.post=com.liferay.CustomPostLoginAction
  - create CustomPostLoginAction  class extend from com.liferay.portal.kernel.events.Action
  - put logic in run method this class and redirect to portlet for add user portrait (for exapmle userportrait portlet)
  - in view.jsp userportrait portlet use "liferay-ui:logo-selector" tag for add and crop image for user.